# MySQL Routines in phpmyadmin - Unresolved Declare Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpmyadmin Routines to write a Stored Procedure called `ViewUserAccounts`.
I am continuously getting ambiguous error messages.
I have one `IN` parameter named `USERNAME` of type `VARCHAR(45)`.

The text within the definition box includes:

```
DECLARE TempUserID INT DEFAULT 0
SET TempUserID = (SELECT idUser FROM User WHERE User.Username = USERNAME)
SELECT * FROM Account WHERE Account.idUser = TempUserID
```

Answer (score 0):

Well...figured it out myself!

DECLARE requires a BEGIN and END and the DECLARE statement must be directly after the BEGIN statement. In addition, all lines required a semi-colon.